# Shortcut Key is not properly working in the form

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net (Windows Application)

In the Form, textbox, combobox etc....

```
  ->  When i open the windows form, if i press ctrl + Enter, then pop windows is opening 
  ->  if i enter any data's in the text box, then i press ctrl + Enter, then pop windows is not opening
```

Code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Sub form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Control + e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            frmList.sFormID = 51
            frmList.Show()
        End If

End Sub
```

When the form load, ctrl + Enter shortcut key is working, once i enter or select any data's in the form, then ctrl + Enter shortcut key is not working (not showing the popup windows)

What wrong in my code. How to solve this problem...

Need Vb.net code help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Form.KeyPreview=True`  and use `Modifiers` flag.

```
Private Sub form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
  If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
     frmList.sFormID = 51
     frmList.Show()
  End If
End Sub
```